# Is there a workaround to get GraphicsContext out of SVGFileDC

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I am writing a small viewer of some scientific data using wxWidgets. As long as it is a graph, it is preferrable to use GraphicsContext which uses floating coordinates, not integer. Also, it would be nice to save the same picture, not only draw it. When drawing at DC (e.g. PaintDC) I may just replace it with SVGFileDC in the new version of wxWidgets and get the file.

Is there some way to do similar trick with GraphicsContext? It seems that (according to [documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.9.2/classwx_graphics_context.html)) there is no easy way to get GraphicsContext from SVGFileDC.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot answer your question directly.  However, it seems to me that you are working at too low a level and are probably 're-inventing the wheel'. I expect you would obtain all the features you need, plus many more you have not yet thought of by using an available, tested and debugged plotting package.

I have used [wxMathPlot](http://wxmathplot.sourceforge.net/) on several projects - it is excellent

[image]

Comment: May be. I had slow and puzzled code written with Matplotlib. I have tried raw wxWidgets and (after dew days of work) realized that the code is few times shorter, significantly clearer, orders of magnitude faster and may be rewritten to C++ in no time. wxMathPlot will not help because it does not produce e.g. 2D color plots at all. Visualization of scientific data is not covered by basic 1D plots, actually.

Comment: Of course wxMathPlot produces 2D color plots!  Did you look at the wxMathPlot website I linked to in my answer?

Comment: I did not find it in few minutes and stopped searching. If you could give direct link to the documentation, it would be nice. Or you mean mpBitmapLayer? Then I see no advantages as compared with the raw wx. Anyway, in my case it is more picture than conventional plot with axes, labels and so on. By the way, are you aware of the fact that wxPython itself [contains plot library](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.plot-module.html)? And it seems to have similar functionality.

Comment: There is already a link to the documentation present in my answer.  Just click on the link and it will take you directly to the documentation - no need for 'searching'

Comment: So, you have no answer for the question. Instead you are trying to convince me to spend my time on another "cool" library. Without any clues to how this will help. Thank you, but no.